# VS online is missing files after a successful opshub migration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

Using the Opshub TFS to Visual Studio Online utility, I migrated a project collection and it finished successfully.  However, after I did a file by file comparison, there are tons of files that are missing from the online version.  Opshub said to post here if there are any issues - anyone know a reason why this might happen and how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything complicated in there? Area all branches in scope for the migration? Are the files random or are they specific... is there a pattern that you can see?

Comment: No - not that I can tell.  Our  repository is pretty straight forward and simple.  The missing files are just basic aspx files, vb files and folders.

Comment: Can you view the history of one of the missing files in the old location and see if there are any branches from way back? Maybe branched in from another team project...

Comment: can you try version OVSMU-V1.0.1.006.exe, also if this will not work then Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location <c or d>:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com Please include a reference to this request in your email so we will provide proper resolution to this

Comment: Ok, thanks - we'll work on it this week and report our findings

Comment: @OpshubInc., was this problem ever resolved? We are having the same problems with a couple of cs files.

Comment: @Micheal : The issue can occur due to variety of reasons. And a lot of successive versions of our utility have had fixes. Can you please confirm the version of the utility that you have installed and share with us the logs at ovsmu@opshub.com? Thanks